# Ajax Load Vs Pagination

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

Is there a 'right' way to load lists of data/classifieds/articles on a web page, I'm currently loading 8 items via an AJAX request with a view more option at the bottom of these 8 items which once clicked will load the next 8 items and so on until there are no more new items to display.

I was looking around and there is an almost 50/50 split between Ajax loading and pagination listing for data depending on what website you look at. I'm wondering is it easier for a user to use one or the other or is it all the same these days and it's just down to me as the developer to decided?

I know that if I go down the pagination route it removes the overhead of an javascript or jquery needed to be used which is a negligible difference.

Technically it doesn't matter either way to me as I've implement both options before numerous times.

This is more a question of user experience then a coding issue.